# Graphical oddities in Start menu, Action Center

Tags: start-menu, windows-10-v1511, action-center

I have been seeing graphical oddities in both the Start menu and notifications in the Action Center. Namely, all interactive objects are darker than normal, and mousing over them further darkens them:

[image: Start menu, showing darkened tiles and objects]

EDIT: There doesn't seem to be a limit on how many times this happens, eventually resulting in all objects appearing black.

[image: Start menu, with all objects nearly blackened out]

SECOND EDIT: I have just noticed that the same issue is also prevalent in Jump Lists both in the Start menu and on the taskbar.

This doesn't affect other users, and removing any updates does not solve the problem. Has this been documented yet, and if so is there any way I can manually fix this?

Comment: if you uninstall the suspect update, does it revert to what you'd expect?  have you tried in Safe Mode, and/or while logged in as a different user?  Does it behave the same way in those scenarios as well?

Comment: Removing the update did not solve the problem, but the issue does not appear to affect other users (tested with creation of a basic local account).

Comment: Then the update is not your cause, it's something specific to your user account.  You should edit and update your question to reflect what you've tested/found (that removing the update doesn't help, that other users work OK, etc.).  Because as-is, the answer is "it's not a bug, and reinstalling Windows is one of many ways to manually fix it.", which doesn't really help anyone... ;)

Comment: Right. I will update the content.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have found the solution through trial and error. It was nothing to do with Windows, rather a problem with my graphics driver's configuration. I returned the 3D settings of the driver to their defaults and did a log-in cycle, and the symptoms are no longer present. I'll have the question marked as closed. Thanks for motivating me to figure it out. :v

Comment: I believe that it is OK to answer your own question (include especially the GPU manufacturer name and the setting you altered) and then mark it as accepted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution through trial and error. It was nothing to do with Windows, as it was a problem with my configuration of Intel Integrated Graphics. I returned the 3D settings to their defaults and did a log-in cycle, and the symptoms are no longer present. Here's the default configuration, however I believe the issue was solely caused by my having set `Conservative Morphological Anti-Aliasing` to `Override Application Settings`.

[image: Intel HD Graphics Control Panel]